# opencart2.3.0.2 PayPal standard no shipping address to

Tags: paypal, opencart2.x

I have searched using a lot of key words, but I have not found a solution.

OpenCart 2.3.0.2, using PayPal standard payment to order, but at the PayPal account,

The order shows "no shipping address"

How to make OpenCart submit the shipping address to PayPal when pay by PayPal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OpenCart 2.3.0.2,
go to catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\payment\pp_standard.tpl
edit

```
name="no_shipping" value="1"
```

to

```
name="no_shipping" value="2"
```